# rails javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few custom .js files in my public/javascripts folder. The 'javascript_include_tag' adds script tags to the head element. Are these executed in the order in which they appear. If yes, how do I control the order in which these script tags are added to my html.

thanks,
ash

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are executed in order of appearance, so you just write them in the order you want. If you are currently using `javascript_include_tag :all` then you can include individual scripts instead to get the order you want:

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
javascript_include_tag "script_1"
javascript_include_tag "script_2"
```

Comment: I would like to use the :recursive => true option therefore I am using the :all option.

Comment: @ash34: I don't know of a way to control the order if you're using :all, other than to prefix your file names with numeric indexes to force the order (and that isn't a great option). If you are including all the .js files in all the views, then you could just write individual includes in the layout file to avoid repetition.